# How to save 'department id' and 'user id' of 'current logged in user' while saving a record in asp.net core 3.0+?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, jwt, asp.net-core-3.0, userid

Previously in asp.net webforms I was used to save current user id, their department id, branch id (in case of multiple branches of organisation), branch name etc in cookies and was using this information to avoid extra server calls while saving, updating, retrieving or deleting record and also for tracking that who deleted, updated or created a specific record. But now in asp.net core 2.0, 3.0+ I wander how to handle this thing. I am thinking to handle this by creating claim and saving this information in claims and then using it for good. Am I doing it wisely or Is there any other effective/efficient way of doing this whole practice ? Can I use JWT for this purpose or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class (e.g.,) `MyUserClaimsFactory` that inherits from `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User, Role>` where `User` and `Role` are you custom classes that derive from `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole`.

In that class, override the CreateAsync method

```
public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(User user)
{
    var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
    // Add all the claims you need here.
    ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.Name) });
    return principal;
}
```

Instead of `ClaimTypes` you can also use a string as key.

Add the class via dependency injection:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>, MyUserClaimsFactory>();
```

You can retrieve the claims in a Controller via `this.User.Identity`

```
var givenName = (this.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FirstOrNull(ClaimTypes.GivenName);
```